# About a proof of the Frobenius Theorem on Division Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, division-algebras

I'm trying to understand a proof of the Frobenius Theorem on Division Algebras, but my knowledge of the relevant mathematics isn't really up to scratch. The proof I'm reading is [this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17606191/fieldextensions.gif).

I'm not sure what the notation $R[\alpha]$ could mean. I'm assuming that
$R[\alpha]=\{a+b\alpha|a,b \in R\}$. Why should this be isomorphic to the complex numbers? Basically I want to know what a finite field extension is, and why it should be isomorphic to the complex numbers.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

In the notation there, $\bf{R}[\alpha]$ denotes the subalgebra generated by the real numbers $\bf{R}$ and the element $\alpha$.

Over fields in general, $F[\alpha]$ can look very different from the complex numbers. For example, for $\alpha=\sqrt[n]{2}$, we have ${\bf Q}[\alpha]=\{a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+\dots+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}\mid a,b,c\in \bf Q\}$. In the extension $\bf Q\subseteq \bf R$, the extension $\bf Q[\pi]$ is actually isomorphic to ${\bf Q}[x]$ (this is an example of an extension by a non-algebraic element.)

Since $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\bf{R}$ and not in $\bf R$, this ring $\bf{R}[\alpha]$ is a finite dimensional commutative domain over $\bf R$, so it's actually a proper field extenion. But the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) tells us there's only one such field, and that is $\bf C$.

> *Basically I want to know what a finite field extension is, and why it should be isomorphic to the complex numbers.*

A field extension is just a pair of two fields $E,F$ such that $E\supseteq F$. $E$ can be viewed as a vector space over $F$ in the natural way (just using multiplication in $E$.) This extension is called finite when $E$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$. In particular, extension by an algebraic element is a finite dimensional extension.

Comment: Sorry what what does "algebraic over R" mean? Thanks for the reply by the way

Comment: @JamesMachin Given a field extension $F\subset E$, an element $\alpha\in E$ is said to be "algebraic over $F$" if $\alpha$ is the root of a polynomial with coefficients in $F$. So $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic over $\bf Q$ since it is a root of $x^2-2$, which is a polynomial over $\bf Q$, but $\pi$ isn't algebraic over $\bf Q$.

Comment: Oh so basically you mean there will be a power of $\alpha$ say n when $\alpha ^n=r$ for some $r\in R$? Is that correct? Thanks again by the way.

Comment: @JamesMachin I can see why my example suggests that, but no, that's not what I meant to convey. The right picture to carry is that there exists $n$ such that $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\dots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ become linearly dependent. That means they have a nontrivial linear combination that equals zero... and that gives you your polynomial!

Comment: @JamesMachin If there exists no such $n$, then the set of powers of $\alpha$ looks like the set of powers of $x$, and then you can see why $F[\alpha]$ would be isomorphic to $F[x]$.

Comment: Oh ok! So if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $R$ then $R[\alpha]$ is finite dimensional? And then the fundamental theorem of algebra says that if R is a subfield of $F$, then $F=C$? So that we get $R[\alpha]=C$ (I mean isomorphic not equal to)

Comment: @JamesMachin Yes, right: the only finite dimensional field extensions of $\bf R$ are $\bf R$ itself (dimension 1) and $\bf C$, dimension 2.

Comment: Ok great, well thanks again, your help has been invaluable!

Comment: @JamesMachin No problem... good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I've managed to confuse myself again. How do we know that every $\alpha \in D\setminus \mathbb{R}$ is algebraic? Is it because D is finite dimensional?

Comment: @JamesMachin The statement of the problem says "Let $D$ be an algebraic division algebra over $\bf R$..." this means exactly that all of its elements are algebraic over $\bf R$.

Comment: Oh I didn't read that bit because I assumed I knew what Frobenius Theorem states! On wikipedia's entry for Frobenius Theorem it doesn't specify that the division algebra D is algebraic! Perhaps there's another theorem which states that all finite dimensional division algebras are algebraic over R?

Comment: @JamesMachin Yes, in fact you can probably already prove that given our discussion! If $D$ is finite dimensional over $\bf R$, you are guaranteed that $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\dots\}$ is a linearly dependent set.

Comment: Yeah I think I can, great! Thankyou very much

Comment: Also, I've looked everywhere but I can't find what this "+ with a circle round it" notation is, when talking about rings? In the proof I linked the author speaks of $D^+$ and $D^-$ and the operation  between them that is the "+ with a circle round it." But he doesn't define it so I assume it's well known. Do you know what it is? (Sorry for the relentless hassling!)

Comment: @JamesMachin It's the "direct sum" of rings, and you can get it as \oplus in the math notation here. It means the cartesian product of finitely many rings viewed with coordinate-wise addition and multiplication.

Comment: Oh ok I see, thank you yet again.

Comment: Sorry, I've got yet another question! How would I show that any element in $R[\alpha]$ has a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @JamesMachin One way is to notice that $x\mapsto yx$ is 1-1 on $R[\alpha]$, and since it's finite dimensional, that means it's surjective. Thus $yx=1$ for some $y$. That question appears many times on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if I let $f_y: R[\alpha] \rightarrow R[\alpha], f_y(x)=yx $ defined for all $ y \in R[\alpha]$ then to prove it's injective I suppose $f_y(x_1)=f_y(x_2)$ which implies $yx_1=yx_2$, but don't we need the division property to show that $x_1=x_2$? Surely we can't apply y inverse when working in $R[\alpha]$?

Comment: @JamesMachin No, no divsion is necessary. All that is necessary is that *cancellation* holds in domains, so that $yx_1=yx_2\implies x_1=x_2$. Another way to see that is that $y(x_1-x_2)=0$, and $y$ isn't zero, so...! (Also, I forgot to include that $y\neq0$ in my earlier comment, of course)

Comment: But doesn't the cancellation law only hold if y has an inverse? How do we know that $y(x_1-x_2)=0$ implies that $(x_1-x_2)=0$ for non zero y? I'm trying to prove that $R[\alpha]$ is a division algebra, and all I have left to prove is that inverses belong to it, but it seems that in doing that I have to use the fact that it's a domain. I thought being a domain and being a division ring were the exact same thing! Again thanks for the speedy replies, they're greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JamesMachin What?! A domain and a division ring are certainly not the same thing :) The integers are a domain but not a division ring. $R[\alpha]$ is a domain because it's a subring of a division algebra. Being able to cancel and being able to divide are different. Of course, being able to divide by something implies you can cancel it, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Oh ok I see! Well I guess that's where my confusion was stemming from. So it's finite dimensional and injective. Why does that imply surjective? I think I remember a theorem from lectures stating something similar but I can't find what it's called!

Comment: @JamesMachin If a linear map from a vector space to itself is 1-1, it is onto. You can see this from the rank-nullity theorem, for example.

Comment: Ah ok yeah I should've remembered that, thankyou.

Comment: I'm now at the part of the proof where the author defines $D^+, D^-$, but I'm finding it hard to see why $D^+$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}$ Could I ask for your help yet again?

Comment: @JamesMachin I... can't make heads or tails of that line either. If I were you I'd be looking at a different proof now to see if it's explained better there. The first line is bizzarre too... "assume wlog $D$ is 2 dimensional over $\Bbb R$"?

Comment: Ah ok at least it's not just me then! But I think it is indeed isomorphic, I'm now using this proof as well: http://vmm.math.uci.edu/PalaisPapers/ClassOfRealDivAlg.pdf (the document's quite big so I always just ctrl+f "frobenius"). The problem is that in that one they've gone about it slightly differently and I have issues understanding it there as well!

Comment: Could I do something similar to the paper I linked? Say there were an $x \in D\setminus \mathbf{C}$ such that x commuted with everything in $\mathbf{C}$. Then $x\in D^+$ and $x^{-1} \in D^+$. Since $\mathbf{C}\subset D^+$, we know $D^+$ is of dimension greater than 2, and is also a field. This is a contradiction to the fundamental theorem of algebra. Hence $D^+$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{C}$. Seems too good to be true, there must be a mistake there somewhere!